# Top Bar with rounded corners in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, 19.10, top-bar

I want the top bar on Ubuntu 19.10 to have rounded corners, like Fedora for example. I have searched a lot but without any answers.

Comment: Yes, the round edges of the TOP BAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First determine which shell-theme you are using..
then edit the corresponding css file with below contents by changing your preferred values..

```
  #panel .panel-corner {
    -panel-corner-radius: 26px;
    -panel-corner-background-color: magenta;
    -panel-corner-border-width: 4px;
    -panel-corner-border-color: blue; }
```

[image]